# (Chai) assert.isBoolean is not a function - what i does wrong?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, chai

There are little part of code:

```
driver.wait(function(){ 
    return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.className(errElement));
}, 3000, 'Element' + errElement + ' is not found').then(function(binaryVariable){
    assert.isTrue(binaryVariable, 'is not True');
      /*console.log(binaryVariable);
        console.log(typeof(binaryVariable));*/
});
```

if I enable debug print, in the console appears

```
true
boolean
```

It means that `driver.wait` returns boolean, so I try to check it via `assert.isTrue`. But I recieve error message `assert.isTrue is not a function`. What I does wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use

```
var chai = require('chai');
chai.assert.isTrue(binaryVariable, 'is not True');
```

Simply referring to global `assert` object makes use of NodeJS' own, which doesn't have `isTrue` or `isBoolean` methods.

Comment: No is not reason. I require assert library via var assert = require("assert").
And other asserts does work normally, e.g.
 driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className(errElement))
      .getText()
      .then(function(txt){
  assert.equal(txt, errMessage);
 });

Comment: Yes, it is the reason. Your `require("assert")` gives you access to NodeJS' own assert module, which has the methods listed in here https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html . You call `equal` function, which is in Assert module, but `isTrue` comes from Chai Assert module.